# Is the BlueZ experimental flag actually needed?

Tags: bluez

I installed bluez version 5.23.  I'm able to connect to a BLE device, query its characteristics, and read/write values.  But all the documentation I've read said BLE won't work without enabling the experimental flag:

```
> bluetoothd -E
```

Exactly what features will this enable?

Comment: You can find that information from "ChangeLog" in bluez source. Usually bluez delivers the feature once it's ready and mark it as experimental until it gets stabilized for bugs. So each version of Bluez will have it's own experimental feature. Check here: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez.git/tree/ChangeLog

Comment: That seems to show fixes for each release - how do I translate that into what's considered experimental?